# AVFoundation positional audio not working on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, ios-simulator, avaudioplayernode

I'm trying to play positional audio in a Swift iOS app using `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioEnvironmentNode`. I can successfully play the audio fine and hear it spatialized, shifting between both outputs in stereo, but **only in the simulator**. When I run the same app on an iPhone, the audio plays but in both ears rather than panning when the source is moved around. Is there some special configuration I need to do, like manually handling the device audio output?

I initialize the audio engine and player like so:

```swift
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let audioEnv = AVAudioEnvironmentNode()

audioEngine.attach(audioEnv)
audioEngine.connect(
    audioEnv,
    to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode,
    format: audioEnv.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
)
try audioEngine.start()

let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
audioEngine.attach(player)
audioEngine.connect(
    player,
    to: audioEnv,
    format: AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 44100, channels: 1)
)

player.scheduleFile(...)
player.play()
```

My source files are mono channel `.wav`.

At some point in the future, I change the position of the player:

```swift
player.position = AVAudio3DPoint(x: 5, y: 0, z: 0)
```

This should play only (or mostly) in one ear. When run in the iOS simulator, it does exactly what I expect. However, on an actual device it just plays evenly in both ears no matter what `player.position` is set to. I suspect it has to do with the configuration of `audioEngine`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
audioEnv.renderingAlgorithm = .HRTFHQ // or .HRTF
```